# Second foreach loop breaking (Posts2Posts)

Tags: plugins, wp-query

I've read about a couple of similar issues that Google gave me ([1](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-post2post?replies=2) & [2](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-posts-2-posts-looping-the-loop-without-wp_query?replies=11)), but I can't quite get to the bottom of this problem.

Using Posts 2 Posts, I'm building a table of posts and their related posts on a Discography Template on a music site. I need to use `each_connected` twice to show the relationship between Albums > Artists and Albums > Producers. My main loop calls the album CPT. The issue I'm having is the second `foreach` loop which always returns an `invalid argument supplied foreach...`. I've tried changing the order in which everything is called, I've used `global $post;` just before my main loop, nothing has worked. At this point, I hope it's not something stupid I've done!

Here's the code:

```
                <?php
                $args = array (
                    'post_type'              => 'hhie_albums',
                    'post_status'            => 'publish',
                );


                $query_albums = new WP_Query( $args );
                p2p_type( 'albums_to_artists' )->each_connected( $query_albums, array(), 'artists' );
                p2p_type( 'albums_to_producers' )->each_connected( $query_albums, array(), 'producers' );


                if ($query_albums->have_posts() ) { ?>

                   <?php while ($query_albums->have_posts() ) { $query_albums->the_post();  ?>
                        <tr>        
                            <td><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Album: <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>

                            <td>
                                <?php foreach ( $post->artists as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Artist: <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php foreach ($post->producers as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Producer: <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                <?php endforeach;
                                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                            </td>
                    <?php } ?>

                        </tr>

                <?php } else {

                }


                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
```

Comment: I can only read one `foreach` loop in your code. Are you sure `$post` is an object and `instanceof WP_Post`? What is the full error message. Please remove all the MarkUp and code that's not needed for the final issue, insert some line breaks to make stuff readable, etc. Thanks.

Comment: What is `var_dump($post->producers);`? That is what you are attempting to iterate over in the second `foreach` as it looks to me. The error suggest it is neither an object nor array.

Comment: With the code as above `var_dump($post->producers);` returns `string(0) ""` but it returns correctly when I comment out the "artists" call in the first foreach loop. Essentially, the only conclusion I've come to is that only one foreach is working at a time, for some reason!

Comment: I've still not had any luck with this. Has anybody encountered anything similar?